# JavaScript: 'this' in superclass refers to subclass

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am calling a superclass method from a subclass. When called from a subclass, 'this' in the superclass method no longer refers to the superclass but to the subclass that called it.
This creates problems with inheritance.

Details as follows:

In my project I use a class to construct objects from registered types.
The types are registered from properties, or alternatively from a template based on an already defined type:

```
class A{

createObject(type) {
    let object = null;
    for (let i in this.objecttypes) {
        if (this.objecttypes[i].type == type) {
            if (this.objecttypes[i].template) {
                object = this.createObject(this.objecttypes[i].template);
                object.type = type;
            }
            else
                object = new TestObject(type);
            for (const aname in this.objecttypes[i].attributes)
                object.set(aname, this.objecttypes[i].attributes[aname]);
            //console.log("Object: "+JSON.stringify(object));
        }
    }
    return object;
}

}
```

This works fine in the superclass. However, I have also constructed a subclass with more user-friendly methods. In the subclass, the method called 'createObject' doesn't return the created object. It stores it and returns the object id:

```
class B extends A{

createObject(type,otherargs){
    let object=super.createObject(type);
    this.objects.set(object.id,object);
    /* do things with otherargs     */
    return object.id;
}

}

/* Method to test function. In test class */

templateObjects(){
    let container=this.getContainer();
    console.log("proto: "+JSON.stringify(Object.getPrototypeOf(container)));
    let tt=App.createObjectType("template1","",[{name:"attr0",value:1},{name:"attr1",value:2},{name:"attr2",value:3}]);
    let ut=App.createObjectType("test","template1",[{name:"attr3",value:66}]);
    container.addObjectType(tt);
    container.addObjectType(ut);
    let o0=container.createObject("template1");
    console.log("Object: "+JSON.stringify(o0));
    let o1=container.createObject("test");
    console.log("Object: "+JSON.stringify(o1));
}
```

When I now try to create template-based objects from the subclass, and the superclass code comes to this point:

```
            if (this.objecttypes[i].template) {
                object = this.createObject(this.objecttypes[i].template);
                object.type = type;
            }
```

the 'this.createObject(...)' call results in calling the subclass' createObject-method, thus returning a numerical key, and failing on trying to assign the type to it.

I know I could for instance rename the method in the subclass to avoid the problem, I could send in the class object (the 'this') as a parameter or other tricky stuff.

But is there a more straightforward, idiomatic way to solve this?

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to a class, it refers to the object that the method was called on.

Comment: @Barmar I realize this, but how to solve it?

Comment: There's nothing to solve, that's how inheritance and method overriding is supposed to work in object-oriented programming.

Comment: Probably `B.createObject()` needs to call `A.createObject()`.

Comment: @Barmar - It does (`let object=super.createObject(type);`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to an object, not to a class. In this case, it's an instance of `B` in normal use (even in code in `A` — there's a single object). Since the `createObject` property of the object comes from `B`, that's what you get from `this.createObject` (regardless of where that code occurs).

But there's a more fundamental issue:

When you subclass something, you're saying that it is a more specialized version of the thing you subclassed. That is, `B` is a specialised `A`. That means `B` **is an `A`**. `A` has a particular contract, e.g. it returns an object from its `createObject` method. By changing that return type in `B`, you're breaking that contract. `B` is no longer an `A`, it's something `A`-like except for `createObject`.

So I recommend not doing that, since it breaks one of the rules of subclassing.

You *can* call `A`'s version of `createObject` from the code in `A`, like this:

```
object = A.prototype.createObject.call(this, this.objecttypes[i].template);
```

but I strongly recommend that you don't. :-) Instead, don't make `B` break `A`'s contract. Use a different method for what you're doing in `B`.

Comment: I can agree to what you say. But if it wasn't for this design flaw, it could be really hard to discover the error :-)

Comment: @Marius - It's not a design flaw (in JavaScript), this is how basically every language with inheritance I've used works. (For instance, if you tried this in Java or C#, it would be a compilation error -- subclasses can't change just the return type of a superclass method.) The issue here is breaking the rules which inheritance structures are designed to support. If you want `B` to have a different contract from `A`, use composition, not inheritance. :-)

Comment: The flaw I was talking about was my own breach of contract, what I meant to point out was that if class B also returned an object, it could be much harder for me to see what was happening. But my real issue here is to have the code in A refer to itself (like 'this' would do in Java).

Comment: @Marius - *"... to have the code in A refer to itself (like 'this' would do in Java)"* It doesn't. :-) Not in Java, C#, or other related languages. If you use `this.foo()` in Java from base class code, and the subclass has overridden `foo`, it calls the subclass version. (The only exception is that private methods can't be overridden; using the same name in both classes for a private method doesn't do this. Java and JS have completely different mechanisms for private methods, though. [Well, for methods in general, but even more so private ones.] Your `createObject` is a public method.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. In Java, it would have been different methods based on the signatures (different params and return types), but in JS there is no such difference. I have overlooked this. I'll flag your answer as 'the best' for pointing out the problem. I suppose I'll have to rename the subclass method...

Comment: @Marius - Ah! Yes, quite true. Your `createObject` methods do have different signatures Java, C#, etc. could tell apart. You can do that in JavaScript too -- I'm out of time now, but I'll come back and update the answer to address the different signatures.